# PHP HTTP_REFERER on 301 Redirects

Tags: php, redirect, http-referer

I'm using some `PHP HTTP_REFERER` code on a dev site to display text to visitors from a referring `URL`. Everything works well on the dev site.

When I deploy it to production the text doesn't show. I believe it's because the referring `URL` has a `301 redirect` on it so the `HTTP_REFERER` code doesn't see that it's coming from that specific site.

Has anyone built anything like this where a message is displayed to visitors from a referring `URL` with `301 redirect` on it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here's the code I'm using

[code]
<?php $referral = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
 $referral = strtolower($referral);
 $referral = explode("/", $referral);
 $referral = $referral[2];
  if($referral =='referalsite.com'); { ?>
  MESSAGE HERE
<?php }; ?>
[code]

Answer (score 0):

Major browser still keep the referer in the redirection.

The reason for not showing the referer could be :

- The user opens the url in their new tab or window without hyperlink (probably typing the url or opening bookmark)
- Bot who make the request to the url

Comment: Thanks for answering priyabagus. The first reason, opening the URL without the hyperlink is the issue.

When they visit oldurl.com it automatically sends them to newurl.com. Is there a way to display a message to those users?